# Can't save image with paperclip, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm using paperclip for uploading my image. My app can import images correctly but I can't save them. Here is my controller:

```
def create
    @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
    logger.debug "image: #{@upload.image}"
    logger.debug "image: #{@upload.image_content_type}"
    logger.debug "image: #{@upload.image_file_name}"
    if @upload
      @upload.save
      redirect_to uploads_new_path
    else
      render json: { error: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end
  end
```

HTML:

```
<div class="medium-10 medium-centered row">
    <div class="medium-10 medium-centered columns">
        <%= form_for(@upload,{:action=>"create", :controller=>"uploads", :method => "post"}) do |f| %>
            <%= f.file_field :image %>
            <br>
            <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when i check log:

```
Started POST "/uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-19 17:18:41 +0700
Processing by UploadsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PzxL26+hLSamelcOvU/5C9zK+UeNatRLAeK8mWVKgPs=", "upload"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3c19890 @original_filename="Capture.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[image]\"; filename=\"Capture.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/QUANGD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20141219-4880-1hzz874>>}, "commit"=>"Upload"}
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/QUANGD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/44a50f07b4bdc57740901280f9eddaf520141219-4880-gh60e.JPG"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Capture.JPG (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
image: /system/uploads/images//original/Capture.JPG?1418984321
image: image/jpeg
image: Capture.JPG
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/QUANGD~1/AppData/Local/Temp/44a50f07b4bdc57740901280f9eddaf520141219-4880-nu1ety.JPG"
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Capture.JPG (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/uploads/new
Completed 302 Found in 430.0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My app still imports image correctly:

```
image: /system/uploads/images//original/Capture.JPG?1418984321
image: image/jpeg
image: Capture.JPG
```

But I can't save into the database. Please help me fix that!

Update validate:

```
 validates_attachment  :image, 
:content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
:size => { :less_than => 10.megabyte }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the info you get from Paperclip

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename Capture.JPG (["image/jpeg"]), content type discovered from file command: . See documentation to allow this combination.
```

what you are uploading is not a jpeg image, but it contains a different format. Try to upload an image whose content type matches the file extension.

I would look at the paperclip docs to see how to handle the situation

Comment: I tried to import Sample Pictures of window, but still the same error. I added my validate, may be it's the problem

Comment: Is the file command even working?  That's different from my situation where the type differs because of n unrelated bug: `(inode/x-empty from Headers, [#<MIME::Type: text/html>] from Extension)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the permitted params, it should refer to instructor and not driver as per below:

```
def permitted_params
 params.require(:instructor).permit(..., :avatar)
end
```

Comment: Sorry! i'm not using rails 4 with strong parameter